# Group parents with same children

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, aggregate

EDIT: This is way harder to explain that I though, constatly editing based on comments. Thank you all for taking interest.

I have a table like this

```
ID  Type                    ParentID
1   ChildTypeA              1
2   ChildTypeB              1
3   ChildTypeC              1
4   ChildTypeD              1

5   ChildTypeA              2 
6   ChildTypeB              2
7   ChildTypeC              2

8   ChildTypeA              3 
9   ChildTypeB              3
10  ChildTypeC              3
11  ChildTypeD              3

12  ChildTypeA              4
13  ChildTypeB              4
14  ChildTypeC              4
```

and I want to group parents that have same children - meaning same number of children of same type.

From parent point of view, there is a finite set of possible configurations (max 10).

If any parent has same set of children (by ChildType), I want to group them together (in what I call a configuration).

```
ChildTypeA-D = ConfigA
ChildTypeA-C = ConfigB
ChildTypeA, B, E, F = ConfigX
etc.
```

The output I need is parents grouped by Configurations.

```
Config Group    ParentID
ConfigA         1   
ConfigA         3   
ConfigB         2
ConfigB         4
```

I have no idea where to even begin.

Comment: I still dont get how you asisgn configgroup

Comment: Could you expand a litlle more on your "finite set" of configurations ? Are we talking of 1-10 configurations or 1k-100k configurations ? A SQL fiddle with representative data is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I named your table t. Please try if this is what you are looking for.
It's show matched and unmatched.
It's looking for parentids with the same number of rows (`t1.cnt = t2.cnt`) and that all the rows are matched (`having COUNT(*) = t1.cnt`).
You can try it [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/519153)

```
    ;with t1 as (select parentid, type, id, count(*) over (partition by parentid order by parentid) cnt from t),
t3 as 
     (
        select t1.parentid parentid1, t2.parentid parentid2, count(*) cn, t1.cnt cnt1, t2.cnt cnt2, ROW_NUMBER () over (order by t1.parentid) rn
          from t1 join t1 as t2 on t1.type = t2.type and t1.parentid <> t2.parentid and t1.cnt = t2.cnt
      group by t1.parentid, t2.parentid, t1.cnt, t2.cnt
      having COUNT(*) = t1.cnt
      ),
notFound as (
          select t1.parentid, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by t1.parentid) rn
           from t1
          where not exists (select 1 from t3 where t1.parentid = t3.parentid1)
          group by t1.parentid
          )
 select 'Config'+char((select min(rn)+64 from t3 as t4 where t3.parentid1 in (t4.parentid1 , t4.parentid2))) config, t3.parentid1
   from t3
 union all
  select 'Config'+char((select max(rn)+64+notFound.rn from t3)) config, notFound.parentid
   from notFound
```

**OUTPUT**

```
config  parentid1
ConfigA 1
ConfigA 3
ConfigB 2
ConfigB 4
```

If id 14 was ChildTypeZ then parentid 2 and 4 wouldn't match. This would be the output:

```
config  parentid1
ConfigA 1
ConfigA 3
ConfigC 2
ConfigD 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I have happen to have similar task. The data I'm working with is a bit bigger scale so I had to find an effective approach to this. Basically I've found 2 working approaches.

One is pure SQL - here's a core query. Basically it gives you smallest ParentID with same collection of children, which you can then use as a group id (you can also enumerate it with `row_number`). As a small note - I'm using cte here, but in real world I'd suggest to put grouped parents into temporary table and add indexes on the table as well.

```
;with cte_parents as (
    -- You can also use different statistics to narrow the search
    select
        [ParentID],
        count(*) as cnt,
        min([Type]) as min_Type,
        max([Type]) as max_Type
    from Table1
    group by
        [ParentID]
)
select
    h1.ParentID,
    k.ParentID as GroupID
from cte_parents as h1
    outer apply (
        select top 1
            h2.[ParentID]
        from cte_parents as h2
        where
            h2.cnt = h1.cnt and
            h2.min_Type = h1.min_Type and
            h2.max_Type = h1.max_Type and
            not exists (
                select *
                from (select tt.[Type] from Table1 as tt where tt.[ParentID] = h2.[ParentID]) as tt1
                    full join (select tt.[Type] from Table1 as tt where tt.[ParentID] = h1.[ParentID]) as tt2 on
                        tt2.[Type] = tt1.[Type]
                where
                    tt1.[Type] is null or tt2.[Type] is null
            )
        order by
            h2.[ParentID]
    ) as k

ParentID    GroupID
----------- --------------
1           1
2           2
3           1
4           2
```

Another one is a bit trickier and you have to be careful when using it. But surprisingly, it works not so bad. The idea is to concatenate children into big string and then group by these strings. You can use any available concatenation method (xml trick or clr if you have SQL Server 2017). The important part is that you have to use ordered concatenation so every string will represent your group precisely. I have created a special CLR function (`dbo.f_ConcatAsc`) for this.

```
;with cte1 as (
    select
        ParentID,
        dbo.f_ConcatAsc([Type], ',') as group_data
    from Table1
    group by
        ParentID
), cte2 as (
    select
        dbo.f_ConcatAsc(ParentID, ',') as parent_data,
        group_data,
        row_number() over(order by group_data) as rn
    from cte1
    group by
        group_data
)
select
    cast(p.value as int) as ParentID,
    c.rn as GroupID,
    c.group_data
from cte2 as c
    cross apply string_split(c.parent_data, ',') as p

ParentID    GroupID              group_data
----------- -------------------- --------------------------------------------------
2           1                    ChildTypeA,ChildTypeB,ChildTypeC
4           1                    ChildTypeA,ChildTypeB,ChildTypeC
1           2                    ChildTypeA,ChildTypeB,ChildTypeC,ChildTypeD
3           2                    ChildTypeA,ChildTypeB,ChildTypeC,ChildTypeD
```